# How should I think when implementing Patrick's method?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have implemented [Quine-McCluskey method of boolean function simplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm). I ended up with the table of prime implicants:

[image: Quine-McCluskey prime implicant table]

As you can see my results are the same as [these on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm#Step_2:_prime_implicant_chart). However now I need to create the simplest formula using the implicants. I found out about [Petrick's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrick%27s_method). To me, it seems very human-intuitive, though quite long - but I can't think how should computer apply this method. It seems really like a calculating equation. Computers need a lot of help to deal with equations.
Is there a different way to think about it?

Comment: Did you implement the Petrick's method?

Comment: @Nick Sadly, this is 8 years ago so I have no idea. I don't think so though and the laptop with the code is currently under maintenance indefinitely.

Comment: Look on the QCA package in R.